# Как сделать базу данных для телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Делаю телеграм бота на Python. Функционал бота: покупка товара (т.е. подписки) с помощью free-kassa. Он нажимает на ссылку, переходит, оплачивает и возвращается в телеграм канал. **Нужно занести в базу данных id пользователя в телеграме, время и название продукта**. Как это сделать?

Comment: Вы задаете очень общий вопрос, не очень понятно в чем ваша проблема. Python поддерживает из коробки работу c базой SQLIte. Воспользуйтесь соответствующей либой из стандартной библиотеки, создайте базу и запишите в нее все что хотите.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Есть несколько способов, самый простой:
Делаешь user который равен message.from_user.id или call.from_user.id
Потом делаешь запрос в базу данных isUser:
if (user == None:) # В данном случае пользователь не найден (т.к. база возвращает пустой запрос).
И тут регистрируешь его.
if (user == isUser:)
Тут если пользователь найден